# Execution of script using Popen fails

Tags: python, mod-python, popen

I need to execute a script in the background through a service.

The service kicks off the script using Popen.

```
p = Popen('/path/to/script/script.py', shell=True)
```

Why doesn't the following script work when I include the file writes in the for loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time

def run():
    fd = open('/home/dilleyjrr/testOutput.txt', 'w')

    fd.write('Start:\n')
    fd.flush()

    for x in (1,2,3,4,5):
        fd.write(x + '\n')
        fd.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    fd.write('Done!!!!\n')
    fd.flush()

    fd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your bug:

```
for x in (1,2,3,4,5):
    fd.write(x + '\n')
```

You cannot sum an int to a string.  Use instead (e.g.)

```
for x in (1,2,3,4,5):
    fd.write('%s\n' % x)
```

Comment: I have permissions on the file as 777.

I just switched it to /tmp, your right that would be better for this testing.

The results are the same if I comment out the loop file writes the output is...

Start:
Done!!!!

With them includes the output is...

Start:

Comment: Tx Ron for checking the permissions issue -- prompted me to do a thorough code review and spot your bug, see my just-edited answer.

Comment: Thanks --- I'm too new to python yet I keep forgetting you can't do that like you can in perl.  Now that that is solved I can get on to my problems with the real script. (Think they are environment related.)  I'm going to use this one to spit out the environment.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?  It's hard to see the problem without the error.  Is there anyway that the file is opened somewhere else?

Comment: I don't see any errors.  The script is executed in the background of the service.  The file isn't open with any other application.

I'm new to writing services/mod_python/apache if there should be errors some where, can you point out the log files?

Thanks.